# sap.tnt.sidenavigation how to get the navigation list item is hidden or showing in SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sidebar, sapui5

I am using **sap.tnt.SideNavigation** to show the data. If side navigation is in collapse mode(*Set expanded property false*) and now if we change the size of the window then it will add top and bottom arrow buttons in order to scroll through navigation list items.But then we can see only a few items and all others are hidden. Is there any way to check the list item is **hidden** or **showing** if I have the navigation list item instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such provision available. I tried but i did not found any.
But you can do one thing you can make arraw button hidden and it will scroll though.Only thing is how your user will understand that there are some more item in navigation scroll bar i left it upto you.
Though in case you want to try :

sideNavBar._getBottomArrowControl().setVisible(false);
sideNavBar._getTopArrowControl().setVisible(false)

Comment: No, I don't have to hide arrow buttons. I just want to know whether the list item is within those arrows or not.